# Как правильно настраивать виртуальные хосты в Apache?

Tags: windows, apache, virtual-hosts

Есть каталог `D:\Programs\WebServer`, где располагается связка apache-php-mysql, есть каталог `D:\www`, в котором находятся сайты, каждый в своей папке.

Указание `Redirect /mysite http://localhost:88/mysite` в `httpd.conf` эффекта на дало, включение `httpd-vhosts.conf` и добавление туда записей типа:

```
<Directory d:/www>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
...
<VirtualHost *:88>
    DocumentRoot d:/www/mysite
    ServerName mysite
    ServerAlias http://localhost:88/mysite/
</VirtualHost>
```

тоже безрезультатно.

Прописал в `hosts` ассоциацию доменов с адресом 127.0.0.1 - любой домен ведёт в корень localhost.

**Как правильно настраивать виртуальные хосты в Apache?** Как это делает тот же OpenServer даже без внесения правок в `hosts`?

Comment: Apache не забываете перезапускать после внесения изменений? он конфиг перечитывает только при запуске =)
И да вы точно уверены что *:88 делает именно то что вам нужно?(я про *:80)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, конечно я делаю `httpd.exe -k restart` после правок. Пробовал и `*:80`, но это не то. У меня на 88 порту локальный http работает

Comment: Я просто у вас уточнил =) бывает же всякое =) пару минут, запустится сервер - посмотрю конфиг виртуальных хостов и скину вам сюда пример

Comment: <VirtualHost 192.168.0.99:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain-name.ru
    DocumentRoot "E:\WWW\beta"
    ServerName beta.domain-name.ru
    ServerAlias beta.domain-name.ru
    ErrorLog "E:/logs/beta-error.log"
    CustomLog "E:/logs/beta-access.log" common
    <Directory "E:\WWW\beta">
      Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
apache 2.2 для 2.4 надо переписать пару строк